# RestKit does not map BOOL in 64 bit simulator

Tags: ios, restkit

I need help understanding the error below.

I have a BOOL in my NSObject defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isOpen;
```

In my reskit class I use:

```
 [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{......
                                             @"isOpen":      @"isOpen"
                                             ......}];
```

Has worked perfectly for weeks for all my tests using my iPhone4S and an original iPhone5. As a last test I tested on the simulator on a 64 bit device and I get the following error:

```
 restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:440 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'isOpen' to representation of type '__NSCFBoolean': Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 "Failed transformation of value '1' to __NSCFBoolean: none of the 2 value transformers consulted were successful." UserInfo=0x10cba1c00 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed transformation of value '1' to __NSCFBoolean: none of the 2 value transformers consulted were successful., detailedErrors=(
"Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 \"The given value is not already an instance of '__NSCFBoolean'\" UserInfo=0x10cb86d30 {NSLocalizedDescription=The given value is not already an instance of '__NSCFBoolean'}",
"Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3000 \"Expected an `inputValue` of type `NSNull`, but got a `__NSCFNumber`.\" UserInfo=0x10cbeb400 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected an `inputValue` of type `NSNull`, but got a `__NSCFNumber`.}"
 )}
```

Comment: The iPhone 5S, iPad Air and Retina iPad Mini are the only 64-bit iOS devices so far.

Comment: So presumably my app would not work properly with them? What's the approach to make a BOOL map correctly with restKit?

Comment: Try using `NSNumber` instead of `BOOL`, what happens?

Comment: I can use and NSNumber and a function to then return a BOOL based on the boolValue of the NSNumber but I can't imagine I would have to do that with all my BOOLs there must be a way for restKit to match a BOOL don't you think?

Comment: @Mikael You may want to raise this issue on https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues so it gets fixed properly.

Comment: I got to the bottom of this. See answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mikael says, there is some glitch in RestKit running on 64 bit platform preventing the default conversion from NSNumber to BOOL (and viceversa).

There is, though, a way to make this work thanks to RestKit Value Transformers modular architecture. So, you just create a dedicated transformer class and register it with RestKit default transformer.

This is how the transformer could look like:

```
@interface RKCustomBOOLTransformer : NSObject  <RKValueTransforming>

+ (instancetype)defaultTransformer;

@end

@implementation RKCustomBOOLTransformer

+ (instancetype)defaultTransformer {
    return [RKCustomBOOLTransformer new];
}

- (BOOL)validateTransformationFromClass:(Class)inputValueClass toClass:(Class)outputValueClass {
    return ([inputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]] &&
         [outputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]]);
}

- (BOOL)transformValue:(id)inputValue toValue:(id *)outputValue ofClass:(Class)outputValueClass error:(NSError **)error {
    RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, (@[ [NSNumber class] ]), error);
    RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputValueClass, (@[ [NSNumber class] ]), error);

    if (strcmp([inputValue objCType], @encode(BOOL)) == 0) {
        *outputValue = inputValue?@(1):@(0);
    } else if (strcmp([inputValue objCType], @encode(int)) == 0) {
        *outputValue = ([inputValue intValue] == 0) ? @(NO) : @(YES);
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

You register it like this:

```
[[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer]
 insertValueTransformer:[RKCustomBOOLTransformer defaultTransformer] atIndex:0];
```

Take care of doing the registration **before** defining your mappings.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by my JSON using 1 and 0 instead of true and false. For some reason the 64 bit devices will pick up 1 and 0 as NSString but the 32 bit device as NSNumber. And one device will change that into a BOOL and not the other.

If I drop the quotes around the 1 and the 0 in the JSON then it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something along the same lines as sergio's answer, but in my case the JSON was formed similar to: `"private":0`:

```
@implementation RPBooleanTransformer

+ (instancetype)defaultTransformer {
  return [[RPBooleanTransformer alloc] init];
}

- (BOOL)validateTransformationFromClass:(Class)inputValueClass toClass:(Class)outputValueClass {
  return ([inputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFNumber")] &&
          [outputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFBoolean")]);
}

- (BOOL)transformValue:(id)inputValue toValue:(id *)outputValue ofClass:(Class)outputValueClass error:(NSError **)error {
  RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, (@[ NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFNumber") ]), error);
  RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputValueClass, (@[ NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFBoolean") ]), error);

  if ([inputValue isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFNumber")]) {
    *outputValue = ([inputValue boolValue] == YES) ? @(YES) : @(NO);
  } else if ([inputValue isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFBoolean")]) {
    *outputValue = [inputValue isEqual:@(YES)] ? @1 : @0;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is strange because `"private":0` works for me it's `"private":"0"` that didn't. There is an open issue on github in the transformer section... You should comment there as well because they are having difficulty finding the issue!

Comment: @Mikael Indeed, it was very strange, especially given that the classes were `__NSCFBoolean` and `__NSCFNumber`. I commented on the open issue so Blake can give it a look.

Comment: I have this exact issue where I am posting an object that contains bools.  On 32-bit devices, the bools map to 0 and 1.  On 64-bit devices, they map to true and false.  I am trying to implement your solution but I can't get it to work.  RestKit calls the validateTransformationFromClass:toClass: method but never calls transformValue:toValue:ofClass:error: method.  I registered the transformer globally.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @rplankenhorn This should have been recently fixed in the RestKit transformers, so please update to the latest and see if an issue persists.