# [__NSCFString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My app uses FMDB and Mantle, everything works fine after iPhone 5 simulator but crash prior to iPhone 5s, it looks like Bool Variable is the cause. But I can't get why everything works fine on iPhone 5s, 6, and 6 plus.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isMyFan;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isMyFollow;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger cityID;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger provinceID;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger locationID;

2015-07-14 21:33:17.264 ATOMPSGod[48894:607] -[__NSCFString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79fb7700
2015-07-14 21:33:17.268 ATOMPSGod[48894:607] *** Caught exception setting key "isMyFollow" : -[__NSCFString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79fb7700
2015-07-14 21:33:17.277 ATOMPSGod[48894:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79fb7700'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x026201e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x022ba8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x026bd243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0261050b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x026100ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Foundation                          0x01f3eb39 _NSSetCharValueForKeyWithMethod + 67
    6   Foundation                          0x01ee727f _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 256
    7   Foundation                          0x01ee6731 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    8   ATOMPSGod                           0x0020f1a7 MTLValidateAndSetValue + 311
    9   ATOMPSGod                           0x0020ef19 -[MTLModel initWithDictionary:error:] + 697
    10  ATOMPSGod                           0x0020eb9e +[MTLModel modelWithDictionary:error:] + 126
    11  ATOMPSGod                           0x000e3d54 -[MTLFMDBAdapter initWithFMResultSet:modelClass:error:] + 6836
    12  ATOMPSGod                           0x000e20fb +[MTLFMDBAdapter modelOfClass:fromFMResultSet:error:] + 139
    13  ATOMPSGod                           0x00139746 __25+[ATOMUserDAO fetchUser:]_block_invoke + 246
    14  ATOMPSGod                           0x00299cec __30-[FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:]_block_invoke + 108
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03c124d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03bff740 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 58
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03bff3ea dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 89
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03bff90b dispatch_sync + 37
    19  ATOMPSGod                           0x00299c15 -[FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:] + 341
    20  ATOMPSGod                           0x0013954e +[ATOMUserDAO fetchUser:] + 286
    21  ATOMPSGod                           0x00133c9e -[ATOMCurrentUser fetchCurrentUserInDB:] + 190
    22  ATOMPSGod                           0x0002e9f7 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 663
    23  UIKit                               0x02c3314f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    24  UIKit                               0x02c33aa1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1810
    25  UIKit                               0x02c38667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    26  UIKit                               0x02c4cf92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    27  UIKit                               0x02c4d555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    28  UIKit                               0x02c3a250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x050cff02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x050cfa0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0259bca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0259b9db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x025c668c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x025c59d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x025c57eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    36  UIKit                               0x02c37d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    37  UIKit                               0x02c39f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    38  ATOMPSGod                           0x00112cba main + 138
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x03e466d9 start + 1
)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

updated with variable view:

```
key __NSCFString *  @"isMyFollow"   0x79e50400
obj ATOMUser *  0x79e46e30  0x79e46e30
ATOMBaseModel   ATOMBaseModel       
_boundWeibo BOOL    NO  '\0'
_boundWechat    BOOL    NO  '\0'
_isMyFan    BOOL    NO  '\0'
_isMyFollow BOOL    NO  '\0'
_uid    int 0   0
_cityID NSInteger   0   0
_provinceID NSInteger   0   0
_locationID NSInteger   0   0
_mobile NSString *  nil 0x00000000
_nickname   NSString *  nil 0x00000000
_avatar NSString *  nil 0x00000000
_backgroundImage    NSString *  nil 0x00000000
_sex    NSInteger   0   0
_attentionNumber    NSInteger   11  11
_fansNumber NSInteger   0   0
_praiseNumber   NSInteger   0   0
_uploadNumber   NSInteger   0   0
_replyNumber    NSInteger   0   0
_proceedingNumber   NSInteger   0   0
_attentionUploadNumber  NSInteger   0   0
_attentionWorkNumber    NSInteger   0   0
forceUpdate BOOL    YES '\x01'
value   __NSCFString *  @"0"    0x79e3e140
error   NSError **  NULL    0x00000000
validatedValue  __NSCFString *  @"0"    0x79e3e140
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code, especially from the MTLValidateAndSetValue class?

Comment: Are you using the `charValue` anywhere?

Comment: @luk2302 no, isMyFollow is used as boolean value.

Comment: @Glorfindel, posted the variable view.

Comment: This is an unrecognized selector error, clearly.  This cannot possibly be related to BOOL types as your suspicion and @NKorotkov's answer below.  I feel like you have an intermittent crash which may happen under both 32 and 64bit and it just so happens that since changing all your BOOLs to bool (don't do that...) haven't been able to reproduce it either.  Post some code, and you might get a sane answer.

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace I'd start with `-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]`

Comment: @StephenGroom I think improper use of BOOL-s is leading to some logic error which results in unrecognised selector call. This is my guess.

Comment: @NKorotkov Unless there is something fundamental that I don't know, a BOOL, bool, char, int or any other data type I can think of should all behave the same for logical operations.

Comment: @StephenGroom they should, yes. If used properly. But if you make some assumptions like @(1/0) = YES/NO, which happens a lot when people parse JSON for example, it can lead to different results under 32/64 bit. I can give you an example code if you want.

Comment: @StephenGroom look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22336820/3329130) for example

Comment: Add a simple [category](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35940574/952474)

Answer (score 8):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** If it works on iPhone 5S and higher it seems like 32/64 bit problem since all iPhones since 5S are 64 bit. More precisely for 32-bit system `BOOL` is a `signed char`, whereas under 64-bit it is a `bool`.

You can read more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31270249/3329130).

**UPDATE:** I assume your problem has something to deal with storing BOOL values in collections. BOOL values when stored in obj-c collections are wrapped in NSNumber object, since collections can only hold objects. You should use it like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"BOOL_Key": [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]};
BOOL myBool = [[dict objectForKey:@"BOOL_Key"] boolValue];
```

Or you can use `@(YES)` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithBool:]`. If you don't use `boolValue` you can get unpredictable results. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!This issue kill my day and you save my night , replace all BOOL vars to bool and my app works like charm!

Comment: @PeiweiChen glad I could help. But I should notice that BOOL should work properly on 32 and 64 bit systems. If it doesn't, you are probably doing something wrong with your boolean types.

Comment: Maybe something wrong goes with Mantle as it support above iOS 8.0+ only.

Comment: You haven't needed to use numberWithBool: for at least 2 years, @(someBool) will suffice to box a bool/BOOL into an NSNumber

Comment: @SteveWilford it's true, but I wanted to be more explicit about what happens with value.